# Migrating Azure Service Bus Queue to Topic and Subscription in C#

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

Can I migrate an Azure Service Bus Queue to a Topic and Subscription by just reconfiguring the path names?

Are there any code changes needed?

Will 3rd parties have to change their code if I keep the names alike?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, if you try sending to a topic with the `QueueClient` you will get an exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot open a Queue client for entity type Topic.'
```

Likewise trying to receive from the subscription will result in an exception:

```
Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.MessagingEntityNotFoundException: Put token failed. status-code: 404, status-description: The messaging entity 'sb://ns.servicebus.windows.net/subscription' could not be found.
```

For sending you will need to replace the `QueueClient` with a `TopicClient` which has the same constructor.

For receiving you will have to use the `SubscriptionClient` which needs the Topic as well as the subscription names (so a small change calling the constructor).

`QueueClient` and `TopicClient` both inherit from `ClientEntity`, but `ClientEntity` does not define any virtual or abstract `SendAsync()` method, so it is not easy to make anything truly generic.

The code changes required are minimal, in my case I only needed to change the constructors and the declared types for the clients.

So yes, 3rd parties will have to change their code if you decide to migrate...